# How to stop cursor blinking in Pages

Tags: mac, pages, cursor

I am using Pages '09 on Mac OSX 10.6 (SnowLeopard) and would like to stop cursor blinking. For TextEdit, this was possible by setting

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriod 100000
```

from the Terminal, but this seems to have no effect on Pages. So I would really appreciate any hints or ideas on how to stop cursor blinking.

Comment: instead of 100000, type `-int 100000`

Comment: I tried replacing `10000` by `-int 10000`, but Pages still blinks...

Answer (score 6):

`NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriod` is outdated. As of 10.9, OS S now has separate variables for ON and OFF times. 1000 represents one second. The following 2 commands can be used:

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOn -float 1000
```

and

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOff -float 1000
```

These numbers will set the on blink to 1 second and the off blink to one second (default).

Comment: Thank you @TheBro21 I tried your suggestion, but it did not work either (probably because my OSX is still 10.6). I will try it when I have newer Mac + OSX >= 10.9 (at the moment I cannot upgrade my current one in the office...)

Comment: Try logging out and logging back in